# Existence of prequantization on a simply connected manifold

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a simply connected manifold. Then when, $M$ has a unique pre-quantization and when there is no pre-quantization on $M$.

Comment: You should add more information and define things carefully.  For example, are you considering a simply-connected manifold $M$ with a fixed symplectic structure?

Comment: Yes, I have considered a simply-connected manifold $M$ with a fixed symplectic structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following holds for prequantizations of arbitrary symplectic manifolds:

> **Existence:** A prequantization of $(M, \omega)$ exists if and only if $(2\pi)^{-1} \omega \in H^2(M; \Bbb R)$ is an integral class.
>
> **Uniqueness:** The different choices of prequantization of $(M, \omega)$ are parametrized by $H^1(M; \Bbb R)/H^1(M; \Bbb Z)$.

In particular, if $M$ is simply connected then $H^1(M; \Bbb R) = 0$ and hence if a prequantization exists, it is unique. For a prequantization to exist, the symplectic form must satisfy the given integrality condition.

See Proposition 8.3.1 of Woodhouse's *Geometric Quantization* for more details.